# Updating a Specific Row in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
session_start();
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM images where allowance=0 order by id desc");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
            <div id='img_div'>
            <p><?php echo $row['image_text']; ?></p>
            <img src="images/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" >
            <br><br>
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success app" name="publish" href='admin.php?publish=true'>Publish</a>&nbsp;
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger app" name="reject"  href='admin.php?reject=true'>Reject</a>
            </div>

        <?php   
    }
    ?>
<?php
            if (isset($_GET['publish'])) {
                $test=$_GET['id'];
                $sql1 = "UPDATE images SET allowance='1' where id=$test"; 

                if (mysqli_query($link, $sql1)) {
                    echo "Record updated successfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($link);
                }
                }
                ?>
```

What i am trying to do here is that i am admin.
when users upload a photo, it will have allowance value as '0'.

[click here to see my mysql table with allowance value as 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH0ta.png)

It wont be shown in timeline. 
I will login through admin. So when i click publish, the allowance value is updated as 1 and thus it will be shown in timeline.

the problem here is that when i use this code all of the image gets updated as value 1.

[click here to see my mysql table with allowance value as 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UlA8.png)

I cannot find a specific WHERE condition for mysql command to update my allowance value..

or does anybody have any code for this concept.. 
i.e, user uploads photo it will be stored in database and then after admin approves it it will be shown in timeline...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: actully you are not sending the image id with the click on accept button which causing test value to null. means it will not check the where condition

Comment: @NitinGoyal mysql should refuse to execute that update, or update no records at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['publish'])) {
    $test=$_GET['id'];
    $sql1 = "UPDATE images SET allowance='1' where id=$test"; 

    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql1)) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM images where allowance=0 order by id desc");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <div id='img_div'>
        <p><?php echo $row['image_text']; ?></p>
        <img src="images/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" >
        <br><br>
        <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success app" name="publish" href='admin.php?publish=true&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Publish</a>&nbsp;
        <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger app" name="reject"  href='admin.php?reject=true'>Reject</a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```